# Remove same element string in array 2D delphi

Tags: arrays, string, delphi

This post seems similar to my recent post. But in this question I add more question and more complicated I think.

I have Array like below :

```
R : array [0..200,0..200] of string;

R[0,1]='33332323171787877777444434454445545455434333376777888788444433337887'
R[0,2]='331881818818188181881818112223333333333333377788118111'
R[1,1]='143322217777777777777777777617188118181185554555454554455545455544548'
R[1,2]='333321321111281111881821132132111121181118888787777777777777761555555554'
R[1,3]='3333888818811118111111112111113211321321323233323333333343334344444454'
R etc..
```

I want to remove the same element. So the result will be like below :

```
Result[0,1]='32323171787874345454545434376787843787'
Result[0,2]='318181818181818181812378181'
Result[1,1]='1432176171818181854545454545454548'
Result[1,2]='32132128181821321321218187876154'
Result[1,3]='38181812132132132132323234343454'
```

the result saved in the new array named Result for each like above. 

could you guys help me out?
The previous post I made I asked for 1D array. Thanks if you guys can explain to me. 
Thanks very much. I appreciate all of your answer much, because I'm a newbie in Delphi. and in my neighbourhood I can't ask anybody.

Comment: Are you going to ask next time the same question about 3D...nD arrays? You know how to remove the duplicates from a string, so the main question should be how to iterate this nD arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to your previous question defined this function:

```
function RemoveAdjacentDuplicates(const X: string): string;
```

Simply apply it to each element in the array.

```
var
  R, Result: array [0..200,0..200] of string;
  i, j: Integer;
....
for i := low(R) to high(R) do
  for j := low(R[i]) to high(R[i]) do
    Result[i,j] := RemoveAdjacentDuplicates(R[i,j]);
```

The name `Result` is used by Delphi to indicate the return value of a function. If your variable is not the return value of a function then it would be confusing to name it `Result`. If that is the case I recommend you choose a different name.

---

The key thing for you to learn is that programming is all about creating useful, simple building blocks, and then using those simple building blocks to create something more complex.

Where you need to get to in your programming development is to be able to see the question you asked as completely independent of the implementation of `RemoveAdjacentDuplicates`. That is simply irrelevant to this question. The way to think about your current problem is to realise that you are mapping the same transformation onto every element of an array. It doesn't matter what the transformation actually is. So you might well write a function like this:

```
function Map(const input: array of string; 
    fn: TFunc<string, string>): TArray<string>;
```

whose job would be to apply the transformation supplied in `fn` to every element of `input` and return a new array containing the output of that transformation. The function is trivially implemented like so:

```
function Map(const input: array of string; 
    fn: TFunc<string, string>): TArray<string>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(input));
  for i := low(Result) to high(Result) do
    Result[i] := fn(input[i]);
end;
```

Then you can express your transformation as:

```
output := Map(input, RemoveAdjacentDuplicates);
```

Now, this won't work for you because you have a statically dimensioned 2D array. Which as it happens is a singularly awkward type to work with. However, in this second part of the answer I'm trying to make a broader more instructive point and hope you will forgive me skipping over that detail.